# Grouped Custom Meta Fields without plugin

Tags: custom-field

I need to add grouped multiple custom metas. I did it with CMBII plugin. But if it's possible, I want to create it without any plugin.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Please read [ask]

Comment: If the plugin worked, why not keep the plugin then?. If you really do not want to use the plugin, **you yourself** have to write the code (*or someone else that you hire and pay*), not us. We will help if you get stuck with the process, in which case you **have to** show us your code and explain what is giving you problems

Comment: I don't have any problem. It works very well. I only wanted to ask is there any way make it without any plugin? I wanted to learn. And, I don't use CMBII plugin other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stick with cmb2 -- there is another method of displaying and then saving meta data, but it's a PAIN and loads your functions file. the plugin pretty much has no effect on the front end of the site -- it'll also make your meta boxes a lot cleaner and consistent-looking